# Cannot invoke 'startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I am trying to instantiate CMMotionManager while running the following code:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
  (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
  // 3
  let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
  // 4
  self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25)
})
```

I receive an error: "cannot invoke 'startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue' with an argument list of type '(NSOperationQueue?, withHandler: (CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> _)'

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by changing

```
NSOperationQueue.currentQueue
```

to

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
```